# I want to call an automated check everytime if the 'user' is logged in. If not the 'user' logs in and then redirects back to the (url)

Tags: css, redirect, protractor

In order to keep the test cases as short as possible, I want to avoid repeating the whole login process and clicking every time.

What I want is a function to check if the 'user' is logged in already and combine that with different logic for each case (yes or no).

Let's say I immediately call  `browser.get('/newUrl');` on the first line of the test case. What should happen is: system checks if it is logged in... If YES -> redirect to `/newUrl` | if NO -> redirect to `/login`, login and then redirect back to `/newUrl`

So, I'm aware of protractor's `urlIs` and `getCurrentUrl`, which I've tried to use in combination with a `browser.driver`. This hasn't worked yet, which I kind of expected.

```
  redirectToMandate() {
    browser.driver.wait(() => {
      browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(() => {
        if (browser.driver.getCurrentUrl() !== '/mandate') {
          const loginPage = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Passwort vergessen? (Mail an Admin)'));
          browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(loginPage), 15000, 'Error element taking too long to appear');

          page.valuesForLogin();
          const loginButton = element(by.id('btn-login'));
          loginButton.click();

          const mandateText = element(by.cssContainingText('.AppSubHeader_mainTitle', 'Mandate'));
          expect(browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(mandateText)));
        } else {
          browser.get('/mandate');
          browser.wait(
            until.urlContains('/mandate'), 10000
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

I've started to try something like above, but it doesn't work

I'd appreciate any help possible, thanks!

Comment: When you say test are you referring to the `describe` or it `blocks`?

Comment: it's an ```it```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, within these 20 lines it may have 100 different reasons why it doesn't work. So you really should've posted what error you get

This is my shot in a dark, try it

```
redirectToMandate() {
  browser.driver.wait(() => {
    browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then((currentURL) => { // these two lines
      if (!currentURL.includes('mandate')) { // these two lines
        const loginPage = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Passwort vergessen? (Mail an Admin)'));
        browser.wait(
          until.visibilityOf(loginPage), 
          15000, 
          'Error element taking too long to appear'
        );

        page.valuesForLogin();
        const loginButton = element(by.id('btn-login'));
        loginButton.click();

        const mandateText = element(by.cssContainingText('.AppSubHeader_mainTitle', 'Mandate'));
        expect(browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(mandateText)));
      } else {
        browser.get('/mandate');
        browser.wait(
          until.urlContains('/mandate'), 10000
        );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

if doesn't help, learn to debug, all I can say... eg console.log your url first, then try verify if/else is working, then check every step separately etc...